# how to further optimize this code using Openmp multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

i have this code snippet I came across and I'm trying to use OpenMP to make it run faster than the original version. However, in comparison this seems to be taking about the same amount of time as the older version. Not sure why this multithreading approach is not working to optimize it. Like the timings are still the same. What can I do to make it run even faster?:

```
void sobel(unsigned char *data_out,
        unsigned char *data_in, unsigned height,
        unsigned width)
{
    /* Sobel matrices for convolution */
    int sobelv[3][3] = { {-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1} };
    int sobelh[3][3] = { {-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1} };
    unsigned int size, i, j;
    int lay;

    size = height * width;

#ifdef OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(64) shared (data_in,data_out,sobelv, sobelh,size) private (i,j,lay)
#endif

    for (lay = 0; lay < 3; lay++) {

        for (i = 1; i < height - 1; ++i) {
            for (j = 1; j < width - 1; j++) {
                int sumh, sumv;
                int k = -1, l = -1;
                sumh = 0;
                sumv = 0;
                
                /* Convolution part */
              
                for ( k = -1; k < 2; k++)             
                    for (l = -1; l < 2; l++) {
                        sumh =
                            sumh + sobelh[k + 1][l + 1] *(int) data_in[lay * size + (i + k) * width +(j + l)];
                        
                        sumv =
                            sumv + sobelv[k + 1][l +1] * (int) data_in[lay *size +(i +k) *width + (j +l)];
                    }
                int temp = abs(sumh / 8) + abs(sumv / 8);
                data_out[lay * size + i * width + j] =
                     (temp > 255? 255: temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the main function is simply calling this function like this:
sobel(data_out, data_in, header.height, header.width);

any help would be appreciated!! :)

Comment: Maybe the size is too small to see an advantage (meaning the cost of creating the threads is significant compared to the time the algorithm takes). Maybe you are running in Debug mode instead of release.

Comment: How long does it run? `collapse(64)` should be a typo.

Comment: @Laci this version takes around 0.0028seconds. I tried changing between collapse(2) and collapse(3) and there was no diff in the performance :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best optimization you can apply is to **vectorize** the code. Compilers can often auto-vectorize the code when it is sufficiently simple but this one is too complex for most compilers (including GCC and Clang) to vectorize it.

Manual code vectorization is cumbersome error-prone and often make the code (more) dependent of a specific architecture (eg. x86-64). However, you can help the compiler to generate it for you. To do that, you it better to:

- avoid mixing signed/unsigned types and type of different size;
- use the smallest possible types fitting your needs;
- avoid loops and conditions in the vectorized loop;
- access data contiguously;
- avoid integer multiplication/division with small types (on x86-64 and/or with some compilers);
- prefer using local short-scoped variables when this is possible;
- enable advanced optimizations like `-O3` for GCC/Clang, possibly coupled with `-mavx2` if your target platform supports the AVX-2 instruction set, or with `-march=native` if your target platform is the one where the program is built;
- be careful about aliasing (possibly using temporary arrays, strict aliasing rules, `memcpy` calls, `restrict` compiler extensions, etc.) [thanks to @Laci].

You can check the [generated assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/hGTTETfqf) to see if the code is vectorized or not.

Moreover, using `collapse(2)` should enough here to get a good speed-up. `collapse(3)` can introduce some unwanted overheads due to the last loop being shared amongst threads. `collapse(64)` is not correct (it cannot be bigger than the number of nested loops).

Here is the resulting untested code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

void sobel(unsigned char *data_out,
        unsigned char *data_in, int height,
        int width)
{
    const int size = height * width;

#ifdef OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) shared(data_in,data_out,size)
#endif
    for (int lay = 0; lay < 3; lay++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
            {
                short a11 = data_in[lay * size + (i-1) * width + (j-1)];
                short a12 = data_in[lay * size + (i-1) * width + j];
                short a13 = data_in[lay * size + (i-1) * width + (j+1)];
                short a21 = data_in[lay * size + i * width + (j-1)];
                short a23 = data_in[lay * size + i * width + (j+1)];
                short a31 = data_in[lay * size + (i+1) * width + (j-1)];
                short a32 = data_in[lay * size + (i+1) * width + j];
                short a33 = data_in[lay * size + (i+1) * width + (j+1)];
              
                short sumh = a13 - a11 + (a23 - a21) + (a23 - a21) + a33 - a31;
                short sumv = a31 + a32 + a32 + a33 - (a11 + a12 + a12 + a13);

                short temp = (abs(sumh) >> 3) + (abs(sumv) >> 3);
                data_out[lay * size + i * width + j] = (temp > 255? 255: temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the code to be several time faster (especially true in sequential) -- typically about 10 times faster with AVX-2 since the processor can work on 16 values at once (despite a bit more work related to SIMD instructions).

Another possible optimization you can do is called **register blocking**. The idea is to change the loop so that you work on small fixed-size tiles (eg. 2x2 or 4x2 SIMD values). This should reduces the number of L1-cache loads and the number of char-to-short/short-to-char conversions to perform. However, this is hard to help the compiler so it does this optimization correctly on such a code. It is probably better to use SIMD intrinsics if performance is critical and do the register blocking yourself.

Comment: It is also worth to tell the compiler that `data_in` and `data_out` are not overlapping. It helps auto vectorization.

Comment: @Laci Good point, indeed. I added this point to the answer. This is sad C++ does not have the `restrict` keyword for that (AFAIK any hint of the C++ standard to tell that to the compiler).

Comment: Where do you see the vectorization happening without use the `__restrict`? That's just loads, the address calculation of which shouldn't vectorize at all, just getting hoisted 1/2 loops outward. The sums at the end could just have used the original notion of the kernel, but preferably as `constexpr`. Any real savings / vectorization would come from unrolling the innermost loop in order to avoid reloads, but that's not happening without `__restrict`.

Comment: @Ext3h See the generated assembly in the provided GodBold link: packed SIMD instructions are used for the loads/stores and adds/subs operations like `vmovdqu`, `vpaddw`, `vpsubw`. Not to mention the compiler increase the offset by 32 (ie. 16 items). This means the compiler (GCC) generate a version where there is no aliasing (so there is no need for restrict in the provided code with the provided parameters). The auto-vectorization occurs on the `j`-based loop: several iterations are computed at once.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you for the great pointers! I ran this code and the timing seems still similar to the original (at 0.0028s). Could you advise on any further modifications that could be made to maybe access data more contiguously ? thank you :))

Comment: ***0.0028s*** Most likely means your problem is too small to benefit from multiple threads. You may want to try this solution with OpenMP off.

Comment: @drescherjm yep I have tried with it turned off but the timing is still the same hahah :) Not sure if that means that this is the 'max' that it can be optimized then?

Comment: I added a new optimization in the end of the answer. Indeed, threads may not help a lot for such a short time regarding the target architecture. Nevertheless, if the OpenMP runtime has already been initialized and that it is well optimized, thread should not be recreated and the time to distribute the work should be pretty small (from 1 to 100 us on mainstream modern desktop x86 processors). If the time does not change with OpenMP, please check your compiler flags and that threads are created. Note that memory may limit the scalability.

Comment: As for the same timings, this is weird. It means the compiler already optimized the initial code, or do not optimize the newer one, or that a shared resource like the memory prevent any improvement (which would be surprising on a recent mainstream PC). What is the compiler used, the flags provided to it, the target platform and the image size?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I did find it odd that though that was optimization improvement to the code, the timings was the same. But not sure if it's bc like what drescherjm mentioned abt it being too small. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on release x86. Didn't add any additional flags for this originally, the target platform is windows, the image that was used was around 769KB.

Comment: Can you in any way make the input larger perhaps 4 times as large and test both algorithms with and without OpenMP?

Comment: @MeganDarcy You need to enable OpenMP yourself using the flag `/openmp`. Otherwise OpenMP will not be used. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=msvc-160) for more information.

Comment: @MeganDarcy I just tested with Visual and the compiler is unfortunately not smart enough to vectorize the code (even with the new experimental support of OpenMP simd directives). Thus, the best solution is probably to write your own SIMD code. Note that there are libraries for that (xsimd or Vc for example). Note that Visual also seems not to support the `collapse` clause in that case too... Thus, It is likely better to apply the parallel for to the second loop.

Comment: @JérômeRichard yep I tried it with the /openmp flag but didn't yield any shorter timing. Thank you for checking it out on Visual :) Okay! I didn't know that collapse wouldn't be supported in Visual :( Thanks for the help and pointers!! much appreciated!! :)

Comment: *use the smallest possible types fitting your needs;* - for arrays (and sometimes temporaries) yes, but should clarify not for loop counters / array indices.